# Accessing array values in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a json array which looks like

```
{
[
 {
    "name": "ABCDEF",
    "details": {
        "code": null,
        "description": null,
        "range": {
            "fromNo": "00174",
            "toNo": "99999"
        }
    }
}, {
    "name": "ABCDEF",
    "details": {
        "code": null,
        "description": null,
        "range": {
            "fromSerialNo": "00001",
            "toSerialNo": "00060"
        }
```

}, {
        "name": "ABCDEF",
        "details": {
            "code": null,
            "description": null,
            "range": {
                "fromSerialNo": "00061",
                "toSerialNo": "00173"
        }
    }]
}

and I want the output as 
{
        "name": "ABCDEF",
        "details": {
            "code": null,
            "description": null,
            "range": {
                "fromSerialNo": "00001",
                "toSerialNo": "99999"

```
}
```

But the problem is I cannot put the variable in EvaluateJsonPath as it does not accept nifi expression language. I have to loop through all the values and then get final range. Does anyone know if this can be done in nifi.

Comment: please explain better what you want.

Comment: This is my guess as what you want to do, let me know if it's correct:

It is a JSON array in which each element describes a range of values that it corresponds to.
You want to analyze the entire array to find the smallest "fromSerialNo" and the largest "toSerialNo" in order to create one element (replacing the content) with it at the end with those values.

Comment: Yes. I want to create only one Json object which has only smallest fromSerialNo and largest toSerialNo. I have to traverse whole array to get these values.

Answer (score 3):

Using the out of the box processors there is currently no easy way to do this but NiFi was designed to be easily extensible. What you'll need to do it either write a custom java processor or script to solve this.

For an intro tutorial on writing custom java processors for NiFi check out this link: http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/

As of version 0.5.0 there are the ExecuteScript and InvokeScripted processors. The creator of the processors has written a number of blogs on them here: http://funnifi.blogspot.com/